# How do I alternate the cases of letters/words in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert the "letter_guessed" input to lower case, if it's uppercase and if an uppercase letter already exists inside the list as a lower case  it will return false but I can't get it to work.

I have tried using `isupper()`, `upper` ,`islower()`, `lower()` in many ways. I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong with "if" but can't get it right.

```
def check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed):
    while True:
        """ will work only if you enter one letter and do not contain special letters other then the abc 
        and if its all ready been entered it will show false """

        if len(letter_guessed) == 1  and letter_guessed not in old_letters_guessed :
            """if the letter is one letter  and not already inside old_letter_guessed only then  continue """

            old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
            print("True")
            letter_guessed = input(" : ")

        else:
            """ if its wrong input will print False Try again and if the input is correct it will go back to " if " """

            #old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
            print(False, 'Try again')
            old_letters_guessed.sort()
            print('->'.join(old_letters_guessed))
            letter_guessed = input(" : ")
        #if letter_guessed is letter_guessed.isupper()

new = input()
old = []
check_valid_input(new,old)
```

Comment: standard rule: if you have list then you have to use `for`-loop

Comment: you should use `print()` in differnt places to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it helps to see what program is doing.

Comment: Give an example of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Everything sting has a method called swapcase which swaps between upper and lower case. So:

```
"TEST".swapcase()
```

Would become

```
"test"
```

I'd suggest using that instead of your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop to iterate over all elements in the list with the `.swapcase()` function common to all strings

```py
list = ['some', 'words', 'in a list']
for word in list:
    print(word.swapcase())
```